# How to set SQLAlchemy dialect?

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlite, sqlalchemy

**How do I tell SQLAlchemy which dialect I want to use?**

Context:

I want to store one attribute of my class as a JSON object, and run queries on it using SQLAlchemy. Here is the attribute:

```
winning_team_ids = Column(mysql.JSON, nullable=False)
```

I get the following error at test setup:

```
AttributeError: 'SQLiteTypeCompiler' object has no attribute 'visit_JSON'
```

This seems to be because /sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base has no visit_JSON method. However, /sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base does have a visit_JSON method. Therefore I want to use the mysql dialect.

Comment: Are you trying to use the mysql dialect with a sqlite db?

Comment: @benvc I'm not sure - I know that we use sqlite for unittesting and mysql from devstacks to production.

Comment: Error suggests that sqlite is choking on your json column (which it doesn't support - there might be an extension or something but I am not sure).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dialect matching your database. If you have to use SQLite, you may have to wait for SQLAlchemy 1.3 which adds support for JSON for it.